# How to clear the search result when clearing the edit text in Android?

Tags: android

I have a search in my app. How to clear the searched result when I clear the edit text? Even after I remove the word from the edit text, the searched result remains the same. How to implement this? Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
etSearchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {        
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                            int arg3) {             
            }           
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {

                     String text=etSearchText.getText().toString().trim();
                     if(text.equals(""))
                     {
                           //clear the results here
                     }              
                }
});
```

Comment: hey thanks for the quick reply and pls help me with code that i need to implement

Comment: @PinkCandy: My answer is already explaining what you asked for in your answer.You just need to add these lines of code in your code,along with the code to reset/clear the results.

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy try the clear edit text button given here : http://mytechead.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/create-ios-like-cleartextbutton-in-android/